# Salesforce Apex :- Getting error as static can only be used on methods of a top level type

Tags: salesforce, apex

On developer console ,Getting error as static can only be used on methods of a top level type

Static method which take DML statements input

public class InvoiceHandler {
    public static APEX_Invoice__c insertNewinvoice(date today) {
        List invoiceList = [SELECT id, Name, APEX_Status__c, createdDate FROM APEX_Invoice__c WHERE createdDate = today];
        return invoiceList;
    }
}
This method takes name date parameter and makes a new invoice.It will return that invoiceList.

if i execute only below
List invoiceList = [SELECT id, Name, APEX_Status__c, createdDate FROM APEX_Invoice__c WHERE createdDate = today];

code is successfully executed ,butmy intention is to execute via class and static method

Answer (score -1):

It would help if you indented your code correctly..

```
public class InvoiceHandler 
{ 
    public static List<APEX_Invoice__c> insertNewinvoice(date today) 
    { 
        List<APEX_Invoice__c> invoiceList = [SELECT id, Name, APEX_Status__c, createdDate FROM APEX_Invoice__c WHERE createdDate = today]; 

        return invoiceList; 
    } 
}
```